# Visual Studio Code Python Terminal more cleaner?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I run python code in VSC I get this nonsense that I dont need, Is there a way to remove it? [The PS C:\Users.. thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2u5n.png)

Comment: Use an actual IDE like PyCharm. All that other text shows up because you're using the console directly.

Comment: Have you searched SO before asking, you are probably nr 20 asking this question

Comment: @adrirf1 -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information in the VS Code terminal is useful information. When we click the run button, it executes the run command in "Terminal", showing us the path of the python used and the path of the executed file, which avoids the confusion of multiple versions of python.

If you want to omit the displayed paths, you could click **F5** to debug the file:

(Please use `"console": "internalConsole",` in [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations).)

[image]

Or use the VS Code extension such as "Code Runner".

Comment: I decided to install Code runner and yes it solved my problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding python to system path?
Are you trying to run code like this?

> python main.py

This link has the process for adding python to system variable.
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/